# Select two fields out of three fields from Json data using Linq.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, linq.js

I need to select two fields out of three fields from **Json** data using **Linq.js**

Required output should be

```
[{ "A": -27, C: "country 1" } , { "A": 28 , C: "country 2"} ]
```

using "linq.js" from following path: [ https://raw.github.com/gist/1175460/fb7404d46cab20e31601740ab8b35d99a584f941/linq.js ]

Sample data

```
var Data = [{ "A": -27, "B": -39, C: "country 1" }, { "A": 28, "B": 0 , C: "country 2"}]

var filter = "  x =>    x['A'], x['C']  ";
var findItem = Enumerable.From(Data)
.Select(filter)
.ToArray();

console.log(findItem);
```

code at JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gLXNw/9/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your "lambda" function must return a valid java object.

Your query should be more like this:

```
var query = Enumerable.From(data)
    .Select("x => { A: x['A'], X: x['C'] }") // object initializer
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: and thanks but in  .net linq i used to select fields using     cards.Select(c => new { c.Type, c.Limit }).ToList() ;

Comment: I change the select clause as follows cz i am creating select using run time values.                                                             "x => { \"A"\: x['A'], \"C"\: x['C'] }"

Answer (score 7):

You can use function in result selector instead of lambda (if lambda expression was used not for political reasons :))

```
var findItem = Enumerable.From(Data)
.Select(function(x){
    return {
        'A': x['A'], 
        'X': x['C']
    };
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: it works if property contain space e.g "Hair Cut" where x.Hair Cut will not work, saved my time, thanks